# show that $ ||\ f \,||_{\dot{C^2}} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f''(x)| $ is a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am reading about the $\dot{C^2}$ norm but I am not entirely sure.  It is defined by:

$$ \big|\big|\ f \,\big|\big|_{\dot{C^2}} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f''(x)|  $$

I have heard of the $L^1$ and $L^\infty$ norms (the last one is the [sup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but is this norm the same as $\dot{C^2}$ defined about.  The axioms of the [normed vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) are as follows:

- The zero vector **0** has "length" zero and nothing else.  All other vectors $||\vec{v}||> 0$ have positive norm.
- Multiplying a vector by a scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$ multiplies the length by that constant $ ||a \vec{v}|| = a ||\vec{v}||$
- Normas satisfy the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) -- $|| \vec{v}|| + ||\vec{w}|| \geq || \vec{v}+ \vec{w}|| $

[image]

Is it obvious that triangle inequality holds for the operation I have defined above?  Or anything else for that matter?  Here $f$ is smooth so I have ruled out nice [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) like:

$$  f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & \text{ if }x < 0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if }x \geq 0 \end{array}  \right.$$

or the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) function $f(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Have you ruled out affine functions? If, say, $f(x)=ax+b$, $f^{\prime \prime}(x)=0$, but $f$ is presumably not the zero vector. Unless the space consists of equivalence classes of functions...

Comment: Could you specify what is $C$ with a dot over? Also, the norm in $L^\infty$ is not a sup but a ess sup.

Comment: What is the space in which this norm is defined? This norm may not make sense becuase continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ need not be bounded.